# How can I make \Alph using standard latin letters while using new ukraineb.ldf (babel ukrainian)?

Tags: enumerate, babel, alphabet, ukrainian

Normally, `\Alph` and `\alph` command produce enumeration `A, B, C, ...` and `a, b, c, ...` respectively. Some days ago I installed a new MikTeX version and found, that, while using `\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}`, the same `\Alph` and `\alph` commands are made to produce subset (according to ДСТУ-3008:2015) of cyrillic letters `а, б, в, ...` And I see no way how to switch it back to `A, B, C, ...` but continue to use another advantages of `\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}`

How can I use `\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}`, but return to use `A, B, C, ...` sequence?

P.S. I've already tried to use `\noextrasukrainian`, but it's surely not what's required: just using `\noextrasukrainian` I cannot use cyrillic letters at all...

Comment: You should always add a small example that demonstrates the problem. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is imho no real interface for this, but you can restore the old meaning in \extrasukrainian:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\ori@alph\@alph
\let\ori@Alph\@Alph
\makeatother
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\makeatletter
\addto\extrasukrainian{\let\@alph\ori@alph \let\@Alph\ori@Alph}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{5}
\alph{section}\Alph{section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can do the `\let` instructions also after loading `babel`, which is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm still not sure, is it really good.

In some situations, it works well, but in some others in lead to a lot of errors

`! Missing number, treated as zero.`
`<to be read again>`
`\c@p`
and
`! Undefined control sequence.`
`<write> ...rotect \contentsline {subsection}{\c@p`
`roblem. <<\IeC {\CYRK }\Ie...`
(where `problem` is name of the counter I try to use `\Alph` with; the way I work with it was correct in old LaTeX version).

Maybe it's completely another error, but I'm giving up.